# <img> tag greyed out in firebug hence found the reason for image not showing up. Need help fixing it

Tags: image, gwt, firebug

I'm debugging a website for missing images. The website heavily uses GWT hence the source code is not so verbose. I started debugging it with firebug and found out that the  tags are all greyed out in the firebug DOM source. If I edit the image tag in firebug console, say by adding just a space, then the image tag is not greyed anymore hence showing up on the page.

Can someone here please point out why the image tags are greyed out in firebug and how to resolve this issue. 
Note: there are other images in the page which are working just fine, even they are generated using GWT in the same way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely - the image is hidden (via CSS probably). Click on the tag to see the styles applied to it - most likely you'll see `display: none` or something of similar effect.
As to why the image(s) are hidden - either the CSS rules got mixed up and resulted in such behaviour (Firebug should help with the investigation) or it's part of the application logic (hide the progress bar when not needed, etc).

Answer (score 7):

In my case my image was grayed (greyed) out in firebug due to the image having its height and width to 0 px so effectively it was hidden on the screen. so i deduce that grayed out means its not visible on the screen.

Comment: I had the same reason for a span grayed out.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with social networks icons, and it was also Ad-Blocker (under Firefox) causing it. 
The alternative text of the icons had alt="Facebook" (Twitter, Instagram) in it. Changing that to alt="Facebook_xxx" was enough to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Firebug was showing my container element, which had an img, as grayed out. The element was displayed in Firefox (and other modern browsers), but not in IE8.

Knowing I was setting display:none; and later in the script making it block, wasn't my issue... adding a missing width and height in the style was the fix for me.

For me, it was a matter of explicitly setting the width and height on my div (that holds my img) inside the container div. I did not have width and height on my absolutely positioned div. As soon as I added that the grayed out was solid in Firebug. Also fixed my missing div problem in IE8! (Which was what set me on the debugging path in the first place)

IE8 likes width and height set, where all other modern browsers didn't care and still displayed the div. Firebug showed the element grayed out, but Firefox the browser displayed the div element just fine.

```
  #slidesContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 871px;
    height: 275px;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #slidesContainer div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 871px;
    height: 275px;
    display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Of course after I post, I see TS- gave the same reply like 2 years ago :) Maybe my verbose explaining and IE8 reference will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

As an FYI for other people, I was having this problem and couldn't figure it out - Firebug correctly greyed out the invisible images. I am running the AdBlock Plus add-on and it was hiding the images because they were in a folder called ads. The giveaway was that the images has classes added with random string e.g. class="auwhaezfynjjayjvlasn". I changed the name of the ads folder and voila, visible and not not greyed out in Firebug any more.

Answer (score 0):

Another FYI - my FILE was named xxx-**ads**.swf and the file would NOT display in Firefox or Chrome but worked fine in Safari, IE and Opera.

I am running Adblock plus in Firefox and Chrome.

It seems to me that as a general software practice, Adblock is trying to be too smart in it's detection. Cost me about 2 days of debugging. Grrrr.

Thanks goodness i finally found this forum.